# Import address table read only?

Tags: windows, import, dll, hook

To be honest I'm quite concerned right now. I want to hook the IAT for benign purposes, I know how it works and what I need to do etc., but I read [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20221006-07/?p=107257#:%7E:text=The%20import%20address%20table%20is%20the%20part%20of%20the%20Windows,functions%20imported%20from%20other%20DLLs.), where is states that the IAT is from now on read-only.

However, in that case benign researchers etc. cannot hook the Win32 API functions anymore (only those that are called at runtime via inline hooking). I mean... an antivirus probably operates in kernel as a minifilter driver, so those applications do possibly not need to hook the API,

but still... isn't this to rigorous (it's good because rootkits cannot misuse the Windows API, but for benign tools)..?

Comment: Hooks are observers. Why do you need write access to the data you're observing?